# Mass transfer and thermal gradient

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Assuming that there are two containers, container A and B connected by an orifice. The containers have the same volume and they contain the same gas at the same concentration. Assuming that a pressure gradient is induced by a temperature gradient, will some molecules flow from the higher pressure to the low pressure container? Will there be no gas flux?

Answer (score 0):

There will definitely be a gas flux. The intuitive explanation is that the higher pressure has a tendancy to "push" the particles through the orifice more frequently.

For a more theoretical explanation: One way to look at temperature, pressure and chemical potential are as driving forces for exchanging thermal energy, volume and particles, respectively. If two systems can exchange thermal energy, then their temperature will go towards the same value in equilibrium. If they can exchange volume (i.e. change volume, like a balloon can), then they will have the same pressure at equilibrium and if they can exchange particles, they will have the same chemical potential in equilibrium.

In general, the chemical potential scales with both temperature and pressure, so the container with heightened temperature and pressure will have an increased chemical potential. Since the boxes can exchange particles, particles will flow from the box with the high chemical potential to the box with low chemical potential.

Comment: Chemical potential usually refers to the partial molar Gibbs free energy of a component in a mixture (rather than referring to the entire gas) and is the driving force for molecular diffusion of a species or participation of the species in a chemical reaction.